# In laravel I need to join to models and still use the methods on the first model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-permission

So I have the "User" model and "usersetting" model. the "usersettings" model has a column called "users_id" key to link it back to the User Model.

I'm using the spatie permissions and role module...

So in the Users model I have

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;


class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use HasRoles;
......
public function usersettings()
    {
        #return $this->hasOne('\App\usersettings','users_id');
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\usersettings','users_id');
    }
}
```

**In the user setting model I have**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class usersettings extends Model
{
    use HasRoles;

    protected $guard_name = 'web'; // or whatever guard you want to use
        protected $table = 'usersettings';

        protected $fillable = [
        'users_id','stripe_customer',
    ];

    //
}
```

**And in my Controller I have**

```
public function chooseUser(Request $request){

        $theuserID = $request->input('id');
        \Log::info('The User ID:'.$theuserID);
        $whichuser = \App\User::find($theuserID)->with('usersettings')->get();
        $whichuser2 = \App\User::find($theuserID);

        /*if($isadmin = $whichuser2->hasRole('admin')){
            $whichuser->admin ='isadmin';
        }*/

        #\Log::info('THE HAVE:'.$isadmin);

        \Log::info('THE USER:'.$whichuser);
        #$roles = $whichuser->getRoleNames();
        #\Log::info('THE USER:'.$roles);

        return $whichuser;
    }
```

My GOAL is to return all the user information with the user settings as well as looking up whether or not the user has the admin role. I haven't been able to figure out how to put the three of these together.

I'm thinking that it may be a join instead of a realtion but then I dont' have a uUser model anymore and can't use the methods in the **spatie** package.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

The are some problems you need to resolve.

1. User - User Settings ([One - Many Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many))

You can think user has many user settings, and user settings belong to user.

In User Model, you should define this relationship:

```
public function usersettings() {
    return $this->hasMany('\App\usersettings', 'users_id');
}
```

In User Settings Model, you should define this [inverse relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse):

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'users_id');
}
```

2. [Querying Relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties)

When you accessing relationship, you may simply access the relationship as if it were a property. If you access the usersettings relationship, the return type is [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections).

```
$whichuser = \App\User::find($theuserID);
$userSettings = $whichuser->usersettings;
```

3. [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

You are using `with` in an incorrect way, you should check eager loading:

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
>   data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not
>   actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent
>   can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model.
>   Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

4. Role / Permission

This is the correct way to check whether the user has the specific role. You should fully read [`spatie/laravel-permission`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) to understand their usage.

```
if ($whichuser2->hasRole('admin')) { ... }
```